# SQL Server stops working due to specific sites IIS AppPool crashes it

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

I have a server with multiple sites and I have experienced the following Event Viewer Error:

> Server local connection provider has stopped listening on [ \.\pipe\SQLLocal\MSSQLSERVER ] due to a failure. Error: 0xe8, state: 4. The server will automatically attempt to re-establish listening.

This error occurs directly after one of the sites on my server generates a Warning in the Event Viewer:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 8/4/2017 2:33:05 PM 
Event time (UTC): 8/4/2017 1:33:05 PM 
Event ID: 8fe181c1dde54b359dd40f946cd6d1ae 
Event sequence: 15 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/11/ROOT-1-131463267483252556 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\Hosting\www.testsite.com\ 
    Machine name: S1 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 5856 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\www.testsite.com 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: Win32Exception 
    Exception message: The wait operation timed out



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://www.testsite.com/en-ie/about 
    Request path: /en-ie/about 
    User host address: 90.100.170.80 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\www.testsite.com 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 22 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\www.testsite.com 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace: 

Custom event details:
```

I know that if I turn off 'testsite' in IIS then my server works fine for all other sites. Any idea is it something gone wrong with the AppPool? Something to do in IIS? I am not encountering this problem with this site locally in IIS.

Comment: not really enough info here. Presumably the application in question is overloading the DB or something, esp if it's timing out. Perhaps a long running query is locking everything. Have you tried to profile what happens to the DB when that site is operating? Do you know what this application is supposed to do?

Comment: Hi thx for comments. Application is a website exactly the same as other websites on the same server. Agreed its overloading DB with it timing out (just not sure why). I haven't tried profiling DB (will look into that now thx). Site is having speed issues so I'll address that first and see if timing out is fixed. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I compared site with others on same server and found its App Pool had duplicate applications assigned. I removed one and problem was resolved.

Still seeing the following error in relation to that same site though:

> Message: Unable to find assembly 'Lucene.Net, Version=3.0.3.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=85089178b9ac3181'.

This may or may not have been invoved with the initial db overloading as the EvenLog table was quite large with errors from Lucene (from DNN module 'SearchBoost').